# How to Sum only hours using Sumif() from excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am Calculating Over Time of the employees in time format cell using **Microsoft Excel 2007**. In my result, its calculated as hh and mm. But I want only Hours and ignore Min.

Eg : I have to get this result of SANIA SARWER **0.18** as **0.0**

See the screenshot below.

[image: Here is my Screenshot]

Comment: Walekum Salam. You can also extract the hour from the time column in a helper column using the Hour() function and then use the helper column in your Sumif formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Int(24*$B:$B),--($A:$A=D2))
```

### How does it work?

Well, `SUMPRODUCT` will go through each item and multiply them together (So `SUMPRODUCT(A1:A3,B1:B3)` is the same as `=(A1*B1)+(A2*B2)+(A3*B3)`) - now, let's looks at each of the columns we're multiplying.

`INT(24*$B:$B)` is just Days, converted to Hours, and trim off the decimal part (minutes/seconds) - fairly simple.

`--($A:$A=D2)` first checks if the value in column A is the same as in `D2` and gives `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  The `--` then converts this into `1` or `0`, which we multiply by the hours before adding them all up.

Comment: its not working '=SUMPRODUCT(Int(24*$B:$B),--($A:$A=D2))'

Comment: @WaqarYousufzai If you have Text values in Column B then it will give a `#VALUE!` error - to fix that you need to use the [Array Formula](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) `{=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(INT(24*$B:$B),0),--($A:$A=D2))}` instead

Comment: it worked. but result is 0.97. please see screenshot in your example

Comment: @WaqarYousufzai Using my code, I get 0 hours (discard 50 min) plus 0 hours (discard 0 minutes) plus 0 hours (discard 4 minutes) plus 0 hours (discard 0 minutes) plus 0 hours (discard 3 minutes) for 0 hours.  If you wanted to Discard minutes *after* you sum, that's `Int(24*SUMIF(A:A,D2,B:B))`, for (0 hours, 50 min + 0 hours, 0 min + 0 hours, 4 min + 0 hours, 0 min + 0 hours, 3 min) = 0 hours (discard 57 minutes) and 50 minutes =  0.95 hours

Comment: yes you are right it is working and result is in your example. `1:59 + 5:55 + 3:50 = 11` but i want. like this... `1:59 + 5:55 + 3:50 = 9` i want sum only only only hours..

Comment: Then type `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(INT(24*$B:$B),0),--($A:$A=D2))` and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to convert it to an [Array Formula](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to **Round Down** the data using ROUND function, and then use SUM function to add the rounding data up.

You can find a simple example below.

[image]